# PHP foreach() loop then Insert Single Array Value to MySQL DB with Submit Button

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli, php-curl

After json_decode() I run a foreach() loop to display all the json results along with a submit button for each result. I wrote a mysql INSERT block to post the json results. I'm trying to figure out how to assign each json result a unique ID so that after I click the submit button, that JSON object gets posted properly to my database. What is happening currently with my code, is only the last value in the array is getting posted and not the value that I am trying to submit.

I've tried iterating over the foreach() loop and using the iterator as an assigned unique ID. Didn't work. I tried creating checkboxes next to the submit buttons and this did not work out either. I'm not sure if it's my code placement or why I'm only able to post the last value in the array.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$provider_first_name = 'Henry';
$provider_last_name = 'Lee';
$provider_state = 'CA';
$provider_postal_code = '';

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api?first_name=". $provider_first_name . "&last_name=" . $provider_last_name . "&state=" . $provider_state . "&postal_code=" . $provider_postal_code . "",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",

));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$json = json_decode($response, TRUE);
```

/** 10 Henry Lee Results Will Display from foreach() Loop **/

```
$i = 0;

foreach($json['results'] as $doc){
/** JSON Responses Listed Below **/

  $p_name = $doc['basic']['first_name'] . " " . $doc['basic']['last_name'] . ", " . $doc['basic']['credential'];

  $p_npi = $doc['number'];

  $p_address_one = $doc['addresses'][0]['address_1'];

  $p_address_two = $doc['addresses'][0]['city'] . ", " . $doc['addresses'][0]['state'] . " " . $doc['addresses'][0]['postal_code'];

  $p_skills = $doc['taxonomies'][0]['desc'];

  $p_phone = $doc['addresses'][1]['telephone_number'];

  if(empty($doc['addresses'][1]['telephone_number'])){

    $p_phone = 'Not Available';
  }

  //** Echo Each Array Value In Bordered Card **/

  echo "
       <div class='col-md-4 col-sm-12 wow fadeIn' style='padding-top: 9px;'>
         <div class='card border border-secondary mb-3' style='max-width: 18rem;'>
           <div class='card-header text-center'>
             <i class='fa fa-user-md' aria-hidden='true'></i> $p_name
           </div>
           <div class='card-body text-primary text-center'>

             <p class='card-text text-center'>
               NPI Number: $p_npi
             </p>

             <p class='card-text text-center'>
               $i 
             </p>

             <p class='card-text text-center'>
               <i class='fa fa-map-marker' aria-hidden='true'></i> $p_address_one 
             </p>

             <p class='card-text text-center'>
               $p_address_two 
             </p>

             <p class='card-text text-center'>
               <i class='fa fa-phone cyan-text' aria-hidden='true'></i> $p_phone
             </p>

             <p class='card-text text-center'>
               <i class='fa fa-user-md cyan-text' aria-hidden='true'></i> $p_skills
             </p>
           </div>

           <div class='card-footer' style='height: 73px;''>
             <form action='' method='post' id='".$json['results'][$i]."'>
               <div class='form-group'>
                 <div class='flex-center'>
                   <div class='form-row align-items-center'> 
                     <button class='btn btn-pink btn-sm' name='add_doc' type='submit'><i class='fa fa-trash px-1' aria-hidden='true'></i> Add Provider</button>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </form>
           </div>
         </div> 
       </div>
       ";
       $i++;

 }
?>

<?php

  if(isset($_POST['add_doc'])){

    $add_doc = "INSERT INTO user_posted_providers (user_id, provider_name, provider_npi, provider_address_one, provider_address_two, provider_phone, provider_skills, created_at) VALUES ('$user_id', '$p_name', '$p_npi', '$p_address_one', '$p_address_two', '$p_phone', '$p_skills', NOW())";

    $run_doc = mysqli_query($connection, $add_doc);

    if($run_doc){
      echo "<script>alert('Provider Added')</script>";
      echo "<script>window.open('user_provider_search-r.php','_self')</script>";
    }

  }

?>
```

I'm trying to insert the proper array values with my 'add_doc' button in the foreach() loop, but I only able to insert the last value in the array.

Comment: I only see one call to insert. After your `foreach($json['results']...` Did you mean for that last block of code to be *inside* the loop maybe?

Comment: If I place the if(isset($_POST['add_doc'])){....} inside the foreach(), then all 10 records get posted to db. I'm trying to individually select each record to post.

Comment: ok, sounds like you were on the right track earlier. You want some button / link after each item you list that says 'add' or whatever. I would pursue the idea of passing the ID. Each 'item' has a unique ID, those need to get submitted so you know which to add. Either checkboxes and one submit button, or individual submitters per item. Whatever you prefer for UI.

Comment: Is `$doc['number']` unique? Anything actually returned by this service that uniquely identifies the record?

Comment: Yes $doc['number'] is unique. I tried passing this variable in the form as an I'd as well as assign this variable as a button id but am still only able to post the last record in the array. Confused here. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. It seems the submit button can only handle the last record being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

So, might be easier to explain with some code that is just a little bit simplified. I want to show you how to present the user with the form to make their selection, then use those selected values when the form is submitted.

Sounds like you understand the concept for the most part. Guess I am not clear where you got stuck. Let's look at this code using checkboxes and one form. Understand what I have shared, try and implement it, let me know where/if you stall.

```
<?php
//simplified proof of concept...

//your cURL stuff would be here...
$json['results'] = [
    [
        'title' => 'Title A',
        'someIdNumber' => '123'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Title B',
        'someIdNumber' => '456'
    ],
    [
        'title' => 'Title C',
        'someIdNumber' => '111'
    ]
];
//...


//Has user submitted their selection? If so handle it
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //var_dump($_POST);
    /*
    If I check the last two I'd get back the following:
    array (size=1)
      'itemId' => 
        array (size=2)
          456 => string 'on' (length=2)
          111 => string 'on' (length=2)
     */

    //now, loop on the 'results' if in our 'selection'  then do the insert, otherwise skip and check next record...
    foreach($json['results'] as $doc) {
        if (array_key_exists($doc['someIdNumber'], $_POST['itemId'])) {
            echo "selected id: {$doc['someIdNumber']}";
            //in set, do the insert here...
            //$sql = ''....
        } else {
            echo "NOT A selected id: {$doc['someIdNumber']}";
        }
    }    

    return; //->
}



//if user has NOT submitted their selection, then render the form...

echo '<form method="post" action="">';
foreach($json['results'] as $doc) {
    echo "<div>
            <h2>{$doc['title']}</h2>
            <input type='checkbox' name='itemId[{$doc['someIdNumber']}] />';
          </div>
        ";
}

echo '<br/><button type="submit" value="submit">Add Selected</button>';
echo '</form>';
```

Using the actual ID provided is better than using some count in the loop because there is no real guarantee the results returned by this service will be the same rendering the form as they are when processing the form submission. HTTP being a *stateless protocol* and all that.